# jQuery onclick not getting proper values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to get Image ALT values on click event but it's not working as it should be and displays the same value (Image ALT) on click.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0720/9527/products/MDM02-south-east-postcode-district-map-detail-large_ee8e2826-b33b-4c77-83b2-f162df33ec33_large.gif?v=1420644155" class="product-photo-thumb" title="Map 1">
    <img id="imgVariants" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0720/9527/products/MDM02-south-east-postcode-district-map-detail-large_ee8e2826-b33b-4c77-83b2-f162df33ec33_compact.gif?v=1420644155" alt="Map 1">
</a>

<a href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0720/9527/products/png_large.png?v=1420644163" class="product-photo-thumb" title="Map 2">
    <img id="imgVariants" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0720/9527/products/png_compact.png?v=1420644163" alt="Map 2">
</a>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-photo-thumb').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(document.getElementById("imgVariants").alt);
    });
});
```

[>> jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/83cyuozz/)

Am I missing anything?

---

**P.S.: I know IDs must be unique but I wanted a solution that can work even without unique IDs.**

Comment: IDs ***must*** be unique on document context...

Comment: ...and to explain why: Browsers keep a fast lookup dictionary for IDs, which contain a single DOM element against each ID value. This means that `document.getElementById` (and therefore jQuery also) can only see the first occurring element with a specific ID.

Comment: @A.Wolff I know IDs must be unique but I wanted a solution that can work even without unique IDs.

Comment: @DipakG. `that can work even without unique IDs` Why that? This doesn't make sense at all...

Comment: @A.Wolff Have you seen the answers posted below? It works without having unique IDs.

Comment: @DipakG. I can ride my bike on the highway, **BUT** should I???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two elements with `same Id`(shouldnt be), remove them and you should use something like `e.target`

here is an working example.. http://jsfiddle.net/83cyuozz/1/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.product-photo-thumb').on("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert(e.target.alt);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-photo-thumb').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
    });
});
```

## DEMO

**NOTE** `ID` must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example where there can be multiple elements with same ID, and yet it will work fine: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83cyuozz/3/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".product-photo-thumb", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      alert($(this).children("img").attr("alt"));
    });
  });
```